# Manga about a middle aged lady who got dragged into another world as some kind of magician/priestess that specializes in barrier magic

Tags: story-identification, anime, manga, isekai

This particular manga is like an Isekai manga and it has a female lead. I don't remember much, but I remember the plot about it.

This Lady was offered the chance to be transmigrated but she declined and said something like "Leave it to the younger ones" cause she was already a middle aged lady with a stable life and job. Then she has to get dragged into the other world anyway, so she just requests for powers.

Her power that she acquired is that she could do something related with a Google search. (sorry my memory is failing me) But it's like having a built-in Google inside her head or something.

Then she gets transported to the other world and she builds this cabin in the middle of the woods or something. I'm sorry but this is all the info I have.

Answer (score 3):

This is [The Savior's Book Café in Another World](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/isekai-ni-kyuuseisha-toshite-yobaremashita-ga-arasa-niwa-muri-na-node-hissori-book-cafe-hajimemashita) (alternative title "I Was Summoned to Another World as a Savior, but Because I’m a Woman in My Thirties That’s Impossible, so I Quietly Started a Book Café").

> Tsukina is summoned to another world and is told by a talking orb who introduces itself as a god that she is to be the savior of another world and that she is to balance it with her high magical power, whatever that means. **Being already in her thirties, she refuses at first and tells the orb to leave it to those that are younger.** ... **In response, she asks to have the strongest protection magic and requests for a function that allows her to summon any item as long as she googles for it.**

She is depicted as having a steady job and friends she enjoys being with. She has no interest in this god's offer of reincarnation, and states that since a bunch of teenagers happily went, there's no need to drag her into this.

Among the powers she requests are "being able to use the strongest defensive magic immediately" and "A pendant that will open a search screen in your head that will produce whatever you think of", which matches the "barrier magic" and "Google search"  in your description. Upon reincarnating, she creates a small cabin in the woods that acts as a book café.